# Filtering list based on instance type

Tags: list, kotlin, filter, collections, instance

I've a list of different objects extending from the same parent class. I want to remove only 2 objects from the list based on the instance type. I found filterInstanceOf() but it actually returns the object that matches this filter.

```
val objectList = listOf(object1, object2, object3, object4)
```

I want to do something like:

```
objectList.filterInstanceIsNot(object2).filterInstanceIsNot(object3)
```

or

```
objectList.filter { it is! object2 && it is! object3)
```

how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second variant is workable, just set `!` before `is`

```
objectList.filter { it !is object2 && it !is object3)
```

Answer (score 2):

The point of `filterIsInstance` is that it returns a List with a more specific type than the input Iterable you gave it. For example, if you have a `List<Number>` and call `filterIsInstance<Int>()` on it, the return value is the more specific `List<Int>`.

If you are doing the reverse, there is no logical more specific type it can give you, so there is no reason for the standard library to include `filterIsNotInstance`. You can simply use `filter` or `filterNot` instead with a lambda that uses an `is` or `!is` check.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a `filterNot` method for the list, which returns a list after removing all the elements that match the passed `predicate`.

```
objectList.filterNot { 
    it is object2 || it is object3
}
```

This would return a list after removing all elements from `objectList` that would be of type `object2` or `object3`.

Answer (score 0):

The `filterIsInstance` function and the `is` keyword work on *types*, but what you're providing as arguments are *instances*. Therefore, I think you need something like this:

```
objectList.filter { it::class != object2::class && it::class != object3::class)
```